# Converter tabela html em XLSX

Tags: html

Só consigo converter para *.xls* ou *.pdf* porém preciso de **.xlsx**.
Quanto mais simples for o código, melhor.

------ Exemplo solicitado ------

Eu uso a plataforma Salesforce, possui algumas alterações em relação ao html porém consegui adaptar perfeitamente, sem problema algum.

```
<!--IMPORTAÇÕES NECESSÁRIAS-->
TODAS IMPORTAÇÕES SÃO ENCONTRADAS NO SITE DO COMPONENTE
https://www.travismclarke.com/tableexport/ -->

    <apex:includeScript
`value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.xlsxcoremin}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Export2ExcelJS}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.TableExportJS}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.TableExport2JS}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.FileSaverJS}"/>`


`<table id="tabela" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>CABEÇALHO</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!registro}" var="reg">
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!reg.Name}"/></td> 
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!reg.Complemento__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!reg.Data__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!reg.Banco__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tr>
        </table>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="exibeOpcs();" />
`

`function exibeOpcs(){    
            $("#tabela").tableExport({
                headings: true,
                footers: true,
                formats: ["txt", "xlsx"],
                fileName: "Planilha",
            });
        }`
```

Comment: O que você tentou fazer? Quer exportar um `<table>` para `.xlsl`?

Comment: Na verdade usarei outro componente de dados, mas tentei de tudo já, usar table, texto simples e tudo que achei pela frente. Qualquer caminho que leve ao .xlsx já ajudara, não importa muito o componente de entrada.

Comment: @Miguel, pense que será utilizado uma <table> simples qualquer. Não terminei o código pois não sei como fazer o que quero ainda, caso não de certo não terá utilidade o código.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obrigado a quem tentou me ajudar de alguma forma.
Achei a solução que queria num componente:
https://www.travismclarke.com/tableexport/

Comment: Não é necessário escrever uma resposta apenas pra dizer "obrigado". A melhor maneira de agradecer é **[aceitando](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** a resposta que te ajudou. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77729)

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo de como usar esse componente?

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 Colega,  a situação é que nenhuma sugestão aqui foi útil, agradeci a quem tentou, mas foi eu quem achei a solução perfeita para a minha situação e quis compartilhar.

Comment: O problema é que você se respondeu mas não demonstrou como resolveu seu problema, apenas colou um link onde supostamente tem a solução. E respostas apenas com links não são recomendadas. A solução te ajudou, mas talvez seja interessante você editar a resposta mostrando como resolveu, para que sirva de exemplo para outros com problema semelhante :)